# Docker trouble with too many link

Tags: docker, build

During a docker build, i have this error :

```
Step 1 : FROM million12/nginx-php:latest
 ---> 09c053597dda
Step 2 : COPY etc/docker-jenkins/default.conf /etc/nginx/hosts.d/default.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 26a29dd01af3
Step 3 : COPY app /data/www/app
INFO[0012] link /var/lib/docker/overlay/99380f87e1572466529c4f668b5e79fe711496e9
85d313cc0d2f45bfdbdb3969/root/var/lib/yum/yumdb/p/939d2078d64d51ff7ad16150745e94
a26085bc93-php70-php-opcache-7.0.11-1.el7.remi-x86_64/checksum_type /var/lib/doc
ker/overlay/9ac18f869f20ba8ba29d2a16f00f2ce6ff1c6d0d1a40192a0efb8933c8ad1c45/tmp
root958106287/var/lib/yum/yumdb/p/939d2078d64d51ff7ad16150745e94a26085bc93-php70
-php-opcache-7.0.11-1.el7.remi-x86_64/checksum_type: too many links
```

Someone has an idea to fix this ? Inside the app directory there are not many file or directory and not that long.
I'm on a ext4 fs on a ubuntu 16.04
Thank you :)

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted, I'm having the same problem

Comment: Any news for you @Nenotlep ? I don't have any solution.

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem but it was because of another reason.
If you use overlayfs as your storage driver (see with `docker info | grep 'Storage Driver'`) you will get the 'too many links' really soon because it uses hardlinks for making the layers and it has a limitation on how many it can have.
So the solution is to change to another, normally overlayfs2 (made to solve that).

Comment: i'm no longer working with this server (new job) so i can't confirm if i'm using overlayfs

Comment: Thanks for responding. But maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: This also was the problem for us and switching to `overlayfs2` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Though this question is now very old, but want to add my point.

This issue can occur when there are too many dangling images in your system. You should clear them time to time or you can create a scheduler to run time to time to clear these dangling images.

Try this to remove dangling images:

```
sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images -q --filter dangling=true)
```

or

```
docker system prune
```

Please refer this to know more on dangling images Click [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes)

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was with a symlink in a directory that was copied inside a Dockerfile. Resolved by removing the link and rebuilding the image.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my docker build and managed to solve it (Thanks OP for the remidner).

My hard disk was slowly filling up, but seemed to have enough space (around 2GB, image was smaller than that) and the part that actually failed was my equivalent of `FROM million12/nginx-php:latest` but it never reported the error there, only in whatever the next command was - even if it was just like `RUN echo 'Ultimate megaforce explosion festival 2017'`.

I noticed that I had a massive amount of images by running `docker ps -a` - most of these were obsolete and I destroyed a bunch of them manually with `docker rmi 8ab6f43e5e9b 87c6109bbdef 3668f4650c4f`... a long list of IDs will follow. You can also batch-remove everything with `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`. I got around ~25GB of free space like this.

After that, the build started to work. The error message suuuucks.

Comment: unfortunately that was also my tmp solution. But after a moment (1 or two month running) i have the same issue. And i cannot clean more space. By the way, i have 32G free on my drive. @Nenotlep

Comment: @PBrun Dang it. Sorry, I have nothing to help you in that case.

Comment: The `docker system prune` command was added to simplify clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

When `docker system prune` no more works like for me, you can use `sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk ' { print $3} ')`.

Many thanks to Robert who posted its comment at https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/474#issuecomment-140585601.